# Possible to create temporary object variables in Unity - or to mark certain object variables for deletion after they're no longer needed?

Tags: unity

I am using Unity Visual Scripting, and mainly using 3 main types of variables:

- Graph Variables - Graph variables are local to an instance of a script graph. They have the smallest scope and cannot be accessed or modified outside their graph.
- Object Variables - Object variables belong to a game object. They are shared across all graphs on that game object.
- Scene Variables - Scene variables are shared across the current scene.

One thing I've noticed is that over time, my Object Variables are filling up with a number of variables that are essentially temporary in nature.  This clutters up my Inspector, and makes it harder to find the critical variables I need for debugging.

For example, I perform detailed calculations for each Object to determine exactly where certain shadows should appear.  I want to keep the results of these calculations as an Object variable, but don't need to keep all of the intermediate variables that I used in the calculation.  These intermediate variables just clog up my Inspector.

Is there a way to delete unneeded Object variables after I no longer need them?  Or a way to designate certain Object variables as temporary in nature?

UPDATE: Upon request, here is a sample graph from the shadow calculations.  Three of the variables mentioned here are sumSpeakEnd, speakEndList and averageSpeakEnd.  They are all Object variables, because this calculation is in a Prefab (the Prefab instantiates up to 15 or so Objects at a time).  But because the variables are Object variables, they stick around forever.  After they've served their purpose, I'd love for these Object variables to disappear and to be garbage collected (if possible).

I could simplify my calculation to use fewer variables, but the question would still remain: how do I get rid of temporary object variables that I no longer need?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [Flow Variables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.visualscripting@1.6/manual/vs-variables.html)? This is equivalent to a temporary variable in the context of UVS.

Comment: @Mangata If you would write a short explanation of what a flow variable is, how to create one and how to use one, then you could post that as an answer.

Comment: @Mangata I could use flow or graph variable, but these particular variables are all related to a specific object.  So I'd like to have an object variable that is somehow temporary.  Is something like that possible, without me building infrastructure of local flow/graph variables to kludge it?

Comment: Edited the question to clarify a bit!

Comment: What would a "temporary object variable" be able to do that a flow variable can not?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the kind of graph script that is causing this pollution? That might help us spot opportunities to clean it up.

Comment: @DMGregory ok, just added a sample along with some context!  i could reduce the number of variables, but the core question I have would remain: is it possible to remove temporary object variables that I no longer need?  Or should I be using another variable type entirely?  thank you!

Comment: I'd second Mangata's query about whether you've tried converting these to flow variables. They look like they should work that way. Object variables are not for data "*about* an object", they're for data that needs to PERSIST with that object. If you don't need object persistence, then you may not need to create such variables in the first place.

Comment: << Object variables are not for data "about an object", they're for data that needs to PERSIST with that object.  >>

Thank you so much... this helped me understand it much better!  I converted all the non-persistent variables I had into graph variables, and it still works perfect.  I am still not 100% on the difference between graph and flow variables, but graph variables show up in the Blackboard so I am using that for now.

If anyone has time to write this all up, I would be happy to accept it as the answer!  Thank you again!!